# jQuery JSON - why am I getting the following error?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

When using: -

```
$.getJSON("admin.php?format=json", { module: "data", action: "allBusinessUnitsByClientName", clientname : $('#client').val() }, function(json) {
    $.each(json.items, function(i,item){
        alert(i);
    });
});
```

I get the following error in the Firebug console:-

```
a is undefined
a))();else c.error("Invalid JSON: "+a)...f(d)if(i)for(f in a){if(b.apply(a[f],
```

The Json being returned is in the following format: -

```
{"550":"Test 1","547":"Test 2","549":"Test 3"}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting this because `json.items` is `undefined` here, you just want `json` (your object being returned, which has no `items` property), like this:

```
$.getJSON("admin.php?format=json", { module: "data", action: "allBusinessUnitsByClientName", clientname : $('#client').val() }, function(json) {
    $.each(json, function(i,item){
        alert(i);
    });
});
```

Comment: Add I see, thanks. Is there a way of validating a Json request? For example, when using $.ajax({}) I could use success or error to check if the call has been successful.

Comment: @user275074 - If the JSON itself is invalid the request will silently fail, you can test your JSON output here:  http://www.jsonlint.com/ If you want general error problems, timeouts, access denied any error messagr from the server, etc, then yes use the `error` callback.  Are those items what you mean?

Comment: Yes, I would like to use an Ajaxloader while the content loads. If I were to use $.ajax() I would use onBeforeLoad (I think).

Comment: @user275074 - Or just show the loader right before your `$.ajax()` call.  If you want a more global solution check out [`.ajaxStart()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) and [`.ajaxStop()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/) which fire when the first request starts and the last finishes (if you have multiple at once, works equally well for a single) - something like this: `$("#loader").ajaxStart(function() { $(this).fadeIn(); }).ajaxStop(function() { $(this).fadeOut(); });`, then you need nothing at all in each `$.ajax()` call :)